# Choosing a shard key for a MongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb, sharding

We have a collection of posts with the following structure -

```
{
  _id: <ObjectId>,
  clientId: <ObjectId>,
  ...
}
```

We want to shard this collection as the number of documents is really huge. Most of our queries will be getting the latest 100 posts of a given client, and then the next 100 and so on, just like pagination. We are trying to optimize for this query, and are not worried too much about the write performance.

We have explored the following shard keys -

```
1. { clientId: 1, _id: 1 }
2. { clientId: 1, _id: "hashed" }
3. { clientId: 1, incrementalPostId:  1}
```

In the third shard key, `incrementalPostId` is an incremental counter starting with 1 (the counter will be different for each client). However, many posts can be deleted, and we don't want to show those posts in our fetch request. If not for deletions, the third shard key would have been perfect for our case because we would have known the exact range of `incrementalPostId` to fetch.

We don't want to use limit and sort because that results in a broadcast query, even if the data is present only on a single shard.

So, what could be a good shard key in this scenario so that our queries are targeted?

Comment: Have a look at [Choose a Shard Key](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/core/sharding-choose-a-shard-key/). You say "`incrementalPostId`  is an incremental counter", then you may fall into [Monotonically Changing Shard Keys](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/core/sharding-choose-a-shard-key/#monotonically-changing-shard-keys) and `incrementalPostId: "hashed"` might be better.